# Particle System is not Playing in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a simple spaceship that has a particlesystem. When I press "space" button, spaceship should fly and particle system should instantiate and play. But it's not playing. It seems in hierarchy as clone but not playing.

[As you see, particle effect is instantiating but not playing. It should play at bottom of spaceship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K88a.png)

Those are codes

```
void FlyShip()
{


    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {

        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);


        if (!takeoffSound.isPlaying)
        {

            // _rocketJetParticle is gameobject. 
            _rocketJetParticle = Instantiate(rocketJetParticle, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 4, transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
            takeoffSound.Play();

        }

    }

    else 
    {
        //Destroy(_rocketJetParticle);
        takeoffSound.Stop();
        
    }


}
```

Comment: Is your partical system set to play on start?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your particle is assign to the script and use the debug mode to check the particle system is working or not

Answer (score 0):

```
rocketJetParticle = Instantiate(Vector3);
ParticleSystem ps =rocketJetPartivle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
ps.Play();
```

Instantiate the gameObject that contains ParticleSystem. and named that 'rocketJetParticle'

'get ParticleSystem from  'rocketJetParticle' gameObject  and named that ps.

play particleSystem that called ps.

and also, I would suggest using gameObject.setActive or enabled
instead of using Instantiate&&Destroy for better performance.